# Swift filter and dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary, filter, closures

I'm trying to use a closure filter to filter people in my dictionary who are under 18. I know how to filter with an array, but I'm not sure how to filter a dictionary.

```
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]
var underAge = namesAndAges.filter { &0.namesAndAges.value < 18 }
```

this gives me the error "Contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
var namesAndAges = ["Tom": 25, "Michael": 35, "Harry": 28, "Fabien": 16]
var underAge = namesAndAges.filter({ $0.value < 18 }) // [(key: "Fabien", value: 16)]
```

What you do is that you use `$0.value` in your `filter`.

Comment: I tried this but I get the same error

Comment: @Tom if you´re using the above code in my answer it will work. Do you use another dictionary of another type in your code? Try to paste my answer into a Playground project and print out `underAge` and you´ll get `[(key: "Fabien", value: 16)]`

Comment: I got it working, thanks!